# Any source code for converting an infix filter to a WFS filter?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, ogc, cql-filter, getfeature

A WFS GetFeature query looks *something* like this:

http://hname/arcgis/services/sname/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.0.0&MAXFEATURES=1001&FILTER=%3CFilter%3E%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3EADDRKEY%3C/PropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E1001%3C/Literal%3E%3C/PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/Filter%3E&TYPENAME=Addresses

But users would want to enter something like "ADDRKEY = 1001" so it becomes necessary to convert the infix expression to a AST and then into a WFS filter.

Are there any reusable solutions for converting an CQL filter into a OGC filter?

- "A=b" is converted into
- "<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>A</PropertyName><Literal>b</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use the OGC Common Query Language (CQL) to generate your expressions and then use the [OpenLayers CQL parser](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cql-format.html) to convert to an OGC Filter. A description of the process can be found [here](http://openlayers.org/blog/2011/01/31/cql-parsing/).